# How to animate a View's property

Tags: android

I want to animate the visibility property of a view so that it appears/disappears smoothly.

how can this be done ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [AlphaAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html) .
Here are some good examples

1. [link](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/android-development-more-animations-part-2/)
2. [link](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343)